# Cannot find button "Show Selected Element only" Eclipse Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse

I've looked over Eclipse many many times, and cannot find this button!  I had to use this and deal with this problem for 2 weeks now; it's getting really really annoying having to re-open the file cause i wanted to find the declaration line.

Please please please help.

Here's a picture:

[image]

([large version](http://oi45.tinypic.com/2jbabk1.jpg))

Comment: I can't understand a word of your question (although I'm an eclipse user).

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2jbabk1/6

Comment: A picture of what? What do you want to do? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Okay, when I hold CTRL and click on a variable of any type, or any declaration type eclipse opens the method or the integer or the class on it's own and cuts off everything else.  It opens the editor.  I posted a picture above..

Answer (score 12):

Customize perspective:

1. Click **Window** » **Customize Perspective...**
2. Expand **Editor representation**
3. Click **Show source of selected element only**

[image: Tool bar Icon]

Comment: That is already un-checked though :/.  I checked/un-checked multiple times, and didn't work :(.

Comment: That's really strange. At least it worked for me :-( -- you could try to attach a keyboard shortcut to this function (Preferences > Keys)?

Comment: It works, in that it will show the *button* that allows you to toggle this feature on or off, I don't think the OP realized this.

Comment: NOTE: right clicking on a toolbar does not show "Customize Perspective" in Eclipse Luna for example (probably removed it for some reason). But anyways, one can find it under *Window* => *Customize Perspective...*. +1 for the tip.

Comment: **UPDATE for Eclipse Mars**: to customize perspective select *Window=>Perspective=>Customize Perspective...*

Answer (score 1):

[Moritz Petersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277252/moritz-petersen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454814/453590) will be helpful if you completely disabled the capability and want to get it back, but the option itself, if available, is under:

```
Window -> Preferences
```

And then:

```
Java -> Editor -> [ ] Only show the selected Java element
```

**Personal tip:** I bind this option to a keyboard shortcut so I can enable and disable it on demand. Very practical to focus on a task but indeed a bit annoying when you want to go back to a full-class view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a bug in Eclipse.
I got the "Show Selected Element Only"- button, when I deselected all Editor Presentation buttons in the "Tool Bar Visibility" tab from the "Customize Perspective..."-menue. --> OK
After that I selected the button again.